# Can't destructure recursive array type that's guaranteed to have at least 1 element

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, type-inference

Consider this pattern in Typescript 5.0.4:

```
interface Parser<T> {
    parse(str: string): T;
}
type UnwrapParserTuple<Ps extends readonly Parser<any>[]> =
    Ps extends readonly []
        ? []
    : Ps extends readonly [Parser<infer T1>, ...infer PsRest]
        ? (PsRest extends readonly Parser<any>[] ? [T1, ...UnwrapParserTuple<PsRest>] : never)
    : never;
```

Say I have a function `example` that guarantees at least 1 `Parser` like so:

```
function actionWithPrepended<P1 extends Parser<any>, const Ps extends readonly Parser<any>[]>(
    parser1: P1, ...parsers: Ps
) {
    let allValues: UnwrapParserTuple<[P1, ...Ps]>; // Comes from elsewhere

    const value1 = allValuesTuple[0];
}
```

TypeScript doesn't allow me to access `allValues` - `Tuple type '[]' of length '0' has no element at index '0'`.

Letting `UnwrapParserTuple` cover `Parser<T>[]` types:

```
type UnwrapParserArray<Ps extends readonly Parser<any>[]> =
    Ps extends readonly []
        ? []
    : Ps extends readonly [Parser<infer T1>, ...infer PsRest]
        ? (PsRest extends readonly Parser<any>[] ? [T1, ...UnwrapParserTuple<PsRest>] : never)
    : Ps extends readonly Parser<infer TAll>[]
        ? TAll[]
    : never;
```

allows me to access `allValues`, but whenever I do, it turns into `unknown | unknown[]`.

[Relevant playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-vhcyr85zC8hiyBS8qxoi1dX97XfPXFR3oM2agL258u2We+x+x9wZu4P8R8+44EJOkbRrG8aIOBIAAOrAGAvqoFY0jmBAZjbnmBg1h4RYliMp4Vni6pXlCN4Np8j78m295YN25C8CQNy6CM6baGmGZZloujIH4y7JrqbHrtmDDUaOzTUZgvCPEER6luca4QNU2bccgLECRx+yeAADN4k5BExKn8fJG6-H+ymJnxrFGb+EjCeRz7iZJNwySMcnsdU1nKapVkmRIWk6aIQA)

How does Typescript *not* have enough information to deduce that `UnwrapParserTuple<[P1, ...Ps]>` has at least one element? Is there a way I can solve this?

Comment: TypeScript cannot do abstract reasoning over generic conditional types; you don't need to map tuples/arrays with recursion, though, you can just use a mapped type, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Wzkqrw). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz This looks great! It works as intended in my use case. I *did* think of using object mapping in this way, but didn't double down on an attempt as I assumed TypeScript wouldn't actually end up recognizing it as an array. Feel free to write the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the body of `actionWithPrepended()`, the type of `allValues`, `UnwrapParserTuple<[P1, ...Ps]>`, is a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that depends on [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters `P1` and `Ps`.  Evaluation of such types is *deferred* until such time as the type parameter is specified with a type argument; such types are essentially *opaque* to the compiler and it therefore doesn't know very much about it.  It can't perform the sort of abstract reasoning a human being might do.

If `UnwrapParserTuple<Ps>` could only be implemented as a recursive conditional type, I'd say you should just use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) and move on:

```
function actionWithPrepended<
    P1 extends Parser<any>,
    const Ps extends readonly Parser<any>[]
>(
    parser1: P1, ...parsers: Ps
) {
    let allValuesTuple = getAllValuesTuple(parser1, ...parsers);
    const value1 = (allValuesTuple as [P1 extends Parser<infer T> ? T : never])[0];
    // assert as one-tuple ------> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

However your `UnwrapParserTuple<Ps>` is really just mapping each element of `Ps` independently of the others, and therefore this can be accomplished more directly with [a mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays):

```
type UnwrapParserTuple<Ps extends readonly Parser<any>[]> =
    { [I in keyof Ps]: Ps[I] extends Parser<infer T> ? T : never }
```

And as such, the compiler will understand that `UnwrapParseTuple<Ps>` has the same keys as `Ps`, and if you index into that type with one of the numeric-like keys `I`, you'll get the type `Ps[I] extends Parser<infer T> ? T : never`:

```
function actionWithPrepended<
    P1 extends Parser<any>,
    const Ps extends readonly Parser<any>[]
>(
    parser1: P1, ...parsers: Ps
) {
    let allValuesTuple = getAllValuesTuple(parser1, ...parsers);
    // let allValuesTuple: [P1 extends Parser<infer T> ? T : never, ...UnwrapParserTuple<Ps>]
    const value1Tuple = allValuesTuple[0];
    // const value1Tuple: P1 extends Parser<infer T> ? T : never
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=17&pln=10&pc=55#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBBKUICcAuSDeAsAFBKlICWw2WAZgsgAoiYaYA8AKgHz7Fn9I4LCAAoo2TAC4k4zJQDmASmkcA3HzIBfYhtLYAnjGQBVYAHdMIGE2GYOAVxgAbCGwZQkEAB7VgAEw9MCBA-AHtgJ30kG1Y2EGB9LgBtAF0eAF5dAXdPHwh-QOCwiKjUrP4AfiQykgFSaRzvXwCkIJDwyOqYrDZKGiwkDgBGLgAaJAA6Kb6B9wAlaGwU8rIqkXnF3ObC9pLo5lj4xNSkKqTh8amJ0wsrbrtHFzcoBfEuFKRpYAgANyxFFb1JDfP6YdRELJ+CDwJzMZA0ezAeDYcjhJDyCDYFBOJwANRATns0AczlcDCGW3yLXucQSYyQ8HC4miHiaVJ2xU6NKOyTSIkBggOWCGDSGlymQlYUAaUCyyiQN0s1iFD1JbCS5PFE3caXBOlqpARSJRaIQJuAAHVyNgABYMIJGfwQPxsAXkykFfa2WmJUYCxnAZmNPKetqcqLcuk1fhcfkGgSS4WirWJlgyuW8eP8Fy4Al4glEqAklxIdLozHY-OE4mPUSpsWTCUqqCKcF1UgB5k-AsQCllkR5-HVou1pAgDwailsz00maYQY8KocT7A35YFKKJIABhSba0+u0RFAkFg9CQAFkrEY-Jn+JRqJg6IgvbFuLf24mxBJpLIFPK1Fkh78AYRgKuYSr3MWZKsiGLRhh0EYqj6vIZAKeDVAAkhQwBIAA1hA+ihDQLIpDKSQYR807Ukhc4LqcgwriCAyHvq-AAPRsUgADCoQnkgNCYLxnhOBgZg2lgECQtCsJBPxiLIqiOEYliOJDoWUFuFOsEeJGvoMkyuDBtsrRFAhL49DyqSxgK9bJo2EyptKLJytIip3CqGmTlqOpcHq8ZGgppqBZa1p2g6VLOq6WZkO6VE6UhPJ+tFHYGSyHpwaZey6byWTWclgq2CK0QNlcjnpvGijvnUOZjqpPYjqSpblipVbqbWIj1imzatgKHFIDVg71VB0iTul8XerRb5Loxa6YFqbnKrYGnuO8-qpd21ZDFBTWDcOUHbruvWcZ2uAbUSW21qKY3mewk2LgxXyzYBB5AA)